# Send the output of one task to another task in airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am using airflow, i want to pass the output of the function of task 1 to the task 2.

```
def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               default_args):
    def getData(**kwargs):
        res = requests.post('https://dummyURL')
        return res.json())  
    def sendAlert(**kwargs):
        requests.post('https://dummyURL', params = "here i want to send res.json() from task 1")

    dag = DAG(dag_id,
                  schedule_interval=schedule,
                  default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1',python_callable=getData,provide_context=True,dag=dag)
        t2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2',python_callable=sendAlert,provide_context=True,dag=dag)
    return dag
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [xcom's](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms), as long as the data you want to pass is relatively small it's the best option.